# socket encoding in Node.js

Tags: node.js

On Windows, I am connecting from an application using FTP through wininet to a node session. Node is acting as an FTP server.

In the windows application:

```
lnFindHandle = ;
  FtpFindFirstFile(hFtpSession,;
  lcfilespec,;
  @lsFileFind,;
  INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,0)
```

On the node side:

```
dataSocket.setEncoding('utf8');
console.log(result);
dataSocket.write(result + '\r\n', finish)
```

The response should be the result of "ls -l", the problem is that the data appears to be getting encoded. The console.log() results in:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 hilltop2 Administ    81529 Nov 22 13:36 20131121085624_MANIFEST_55874.CSV.ZIP
```

In the application I receive:

```
€                    àÛÇ‡çÎ    y> D      20131121085624_MANIFEST_55874.CSV.ZIP ....
```

I also tried:

```
dataSocket.setEncoding('binary');
console.log(result);
var toTransmit = result + '\r\n'.toString('binary');
dataSocket.write(new Buffer(toTransmit, "binary"), finish);
```

What do I need to do to get the text to transmit as is?

Comment: It doesn't look encoded, it looks like binary representations of permissions/uid/gid/size/date. You're not showing a lot of implementation details for the Node-side of things though. What is `result`? How did you implement the FTP-server-part (module?)?

Comment: Hi Robert, result is "-rw-r--r--    1 hilltop2 Administ    81529 Nov 22 13:36 20131121085624_MANIFEST_55874.CSV.ZIP" I can't really show a lot of details on the node side because it is a large(ish) program, I tried to distill it down to the problem.

Comment: Are you generating `150/226` codes to mark the start and end of the response?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that they are the codes being sent. Thinking I might have to put this on Github so people can look at the full project.